# Spring XD, RabbitMq: Partitioned stream deployment in failure

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-xd

In  deploying a partitioned stream into our XD container, the stream failed and we can find into XD container log level an Amq issue. The cause seems to come from creation of XD source DLQ : (*'x-dead-letter-exchange'* is not properly set by Spring XD during queue creation process ?)

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'xdbus.partitioned.0-0' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'xdbus.DLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:478)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:315)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:552)
    ...
```

**Partitioned stream feature implementation**

This feature is described in [Spring XD guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#partitioned-stream-deployment-examples). 
The stream definition is simpler than the guide, we have defined a stream with two elements: a sink and a source to check behavior;

```
 time | log
```

When we are deploying the stream, we set this kind of partitioning configuration:

```
 module.time.producer.partitionKeyExpression=payload.charAt(payload.length()-1),module.log.count=3
```

So, the result expected is:

- the deployment of 1 instance for time source and 3 instances for log sink;
- at runtime, key expression will be used to route message through log instances.

**Our installation setup**

- Zookeeper is installed in cluster. (3 nodes)
- RabbitMq is used as message bus. (2 nodes)
- Spring XD is installed in cluster. (3 nodes)

NB: at XD level, the bus is configure to create DLQ fore each deployed XD 'module'.

Has anyone had similar problems?

Any idea will be well welcomed.
Thanks

here is the full stack:

```
2016-01-15T15:13:28+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKStreamDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for stream 'partitioned': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueue(RabbitAdmin.java:166)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus.buildOutboundEndpoint(RabbitMessageBus.java:631)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus.bindProducer(RabbitMessageBus.java:611)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.bindMessageProducer(AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.java:288)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.bindConsumerAndProducers(AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.java:143)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.stream.StreamPlugin.postProcessModule(StreamPlugin.java:73)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.postProcessModule(ModuleDeployer.java:238)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:218)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:837)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:704)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.queueDeclare(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueues(RabbitAdmin.java:499)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.access$200(RabbitAdmin.java:57)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$3.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:169)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$3.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:166)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1298)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'xdbus.partitioned.0-0' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'xdbus.DLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:348)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:221)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'xdbus.partitioned.0-0' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'xdbus.DLX' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:478)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:315)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:552)
    ... 1 more
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

When binding the producer with partitioned streams we don't check to see if the queue already exists (as is done with non-partitioned streams).

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3734).

A work around is to disable AutoBindDLQ on the consumer side and manually configure dead-lettering with a policy.